# Round off figure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I required results like for number ‘500.000100’ result should be ‘500.0001’. truncate the zeros to last available number.

If no value is available after decimal then value to two decimal e.g return 500.000000 to 500.00

Comment: Kindly share sql query for this issue thanks

Comment: You can't mix datatypes, you either have 2 or 4 digits after the decimal separator, you can't have both. What is the original datatype?

Comment: try : `select cast(cast(500.000100 as DECIMAL(9,6)) as float)`

Comment: I know its a very ugly requirement but we need it :P

Comment: I would prefer to do this in front-end code, not on sql server. Just to be clear: you would be manipulating *strings*  **not** *numbers*

Comment: Can u please optimize this query as it gives 280.00000000000001 DECLARE @num decimal(28,16) = 280.000000000000010000 SELECT PARSENAME(@num,2) + REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@num-PARSENAME(@num,2),'0',' '))),' ','0')

Comment: Can anyone provide me the front end code for this in c# thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with [format](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmgs3YtszUAhUSKlAKHdugDaMQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Ft-sql%2Ffunctions%2Fformat-transact-sql&usg=AFQjCNGl7RgYG4d6TWewopoU7DDsf64xnA&sig2=xiq-Pg5Vg406zTNxoszLNA) function. Like this...

```
declare @d as decimal(19, 6)

set @d = 50000.123456

select
    (case
        when @d / convert(int, @d) = 1. then format(@d, '#.00')
        else format(@d, '#.####')
    end) as FormatD

set @d = 500.000000

select
    (case
        when @d / convert(int, @d) = 1. then format(@d, '#.00')
        else format(@d, '#.####')
    end) as FormatD
```

Comment: Can u please optimize this query as it gives 280.00000000000001 
DECLARE @num decimal(28,16) = 280.000000000000010000 SELECT PARSENAME(@num,2) + REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@num-PARSENAME(@num,2),'0',' '))),' ','0')

Answer (score 0):

Use format function.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(
  val DECIMAL(18,9)
);

INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (1.1);
INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (2.32);
INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (33.501);
INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (444.0060100);
INSERT INTO @test (val) VALUES (5555.00600000100);

SELECT val, format(val, '0.00################') formatted
FROM @test;
```

Comment: Thanks Ryszard Kozlowski, but I need a script which work for the huge number of values in column.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for, but if you need to support maximum number of digits after decimal point then you just need to add more '#' characters in the formatting string, e.g.: 
    `SELECT val, format(val, 
    '0.00####################################') formatted
    FROM @test;`